# Why do I have no hibernation mode in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

I have installed Windows 7 two days ago.

Why is there no hibernation mode in my licensed Windows 7 Ultimate?

I have tried using these commands to enable it, but they didn't work:

```
powercfg -h on
powercfg -hibernate on
```

What could be the problem? On Windows XP, I was able to hibernate.

Things I've checked:

- I've looked under the arrow next to Shutdown, it's not there.
- I have executed the above commands with admin privileges.
- I have installed the latest drivers.

**Edit**
Hybrid Sleep was enabled, after I disabled it, the Hibernation mode button appiered.

Comment: Have you looked under the arrow next to Shutdown?

Comment: Thats the problem, it isn't there.

Comment: Did you execute these commands as administrator? See the last FAQ [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Command-Prompt-frequently-asked-questions).

Comment: Yes, executed with admin

Comment: The second FAQ [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Sleep-and-hibernation-frequently-asked-questions) lists some causes that you could check. Also check out if the [power options](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/power-management) are set right. Given that you installed this 2 days ago, it might be the case that you haven't installed all drivers?

Comment: I have latest drivers :)

Comment: Given that Windows XP works I believe it's not the BIOS, the only suggestion left is that Hybrid Sleep could be enabled in your Power Options; but, it would be weird if they were different from their default settings. Does manually executing `shutdown /h` work regardless?

Comment: Yes Hybrid Sleep is enabled. Do i need to turn it off?

Comment: You should do powercfg -energy.  I'll bet it'll come back with a problem.

Comment: @Robrok: Yes, as the [second FAQ on Sleep/Hiberantion](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Sleep-and-hibernation-frequently-asked-questions) of Microsoft mentions. I've made up an answer...

Comment: Keep in mind that even if that button is not there, you still may be able to hibernate with the power button: check Control Panel > 'Change what the power buttons do'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Hybrid Sleep is most likely causing this, [see the second FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Sleep-and-hibernation-frequently-asked-questions). Disable it by turning it's setting to Off.

### What is Hybrid Sleep?

> Hybrid sleep is another new power-saving feature designed primarily for desktop computers. Hybrid sleep saves any open documents and programs to memory and to your hard disk, and then puts your computer into a low-power state.
>
> Unlike mobile PCs, desktop computers typically don't have battery-based power backup. So if a sudden power failure occurs to a desktop computer in standard sleep mode, data loss could occur.
>
> But with hybrid sleep turned on, Windows can restore your work from your hard disk. On desktop computers, hybrid sleep is typically turned on by default.
>
> When hybrid sleep is turned on, clicking Sleep automatically puts your computer into hybrid sleep. When hybrid sleep is turned off, or if your computer doesn't support hybrid sleep, clicking Sleep puts the computer to sleep.
>
> — [Microsoft - Turn off a computer FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Turn-off-a-computer-frequently-asked-questions)

### How does Hybrid Sleep relate to Hibernate?

Hybrid Sleep uses Hibernate to save the memory to disk, but doesn't actually hibernate the computer.

It can be configured to hibernate the computer after a certain time, which disallows manual hibernation...

### To turn Hybrid Sleep on or off:

> - Open **Power Options** by clicking the **Start** button, clicking **Control Panel**, clicking **System and Maintenance**, and then clicking **Power Options**.
> - On the Select a power plan page, click **Change plan settings** under the selected plan.
> - On the Change settings for the plan page, click **Change advanced power settings**.
> - On the **Advanced settings** tab, expand **Sleep**, expand **Allow hybrid sleep**, and then:
>
>   - If you are using a mobile PC, click **On battery** or **Plugged in** (or both), click the arrow, and then click **On/Off**.
>   - If you are using a desktop computer, click **Setting**, click the arrow, and then click **On/Off**.
> - Click **OK**, and then click **Save changes**.
>
> — [Microsoft - Turn off a computer FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Turn-off-a-computer-frequently-asked-questions)

Comment: Hybrid sleep, IMO is more advantageous than either sleep or hibernate. You have the resume speed of Sleep but you also are immune to power failures like Hibernation. It is a Win-Win.